# Notification page CSS broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Confirmed : Chrome 4, Safari 4, FF 3.6, IE8 and OP10.5

Looks like someone either dropped a `clear` or deleted an "empty" spacer div (with a `clear:both;` style).

OFF WITH HIS HEAD!

---

[alt text http://skysanders.net/images/solayoutprob-05-06-10.PNG](http://skysanders.net/images/solayoutprob-05-06-10.PNG)

Comment: Man... you've got some mail waiting.

Comment: Confirmed, same here.

Comment: Same for me in Chrome.  Wait, that *is* Chrome... don't mind me I just got up ;-)

Comment: Same here in Chrome, Opera and IE. The same problem is on the Tag-Stats-page.

Comment: Same in the latest Chrome dev build (5.0.375.29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed.  The same kind of wonkiness also seems to appear on

- on the user profile, Accounts tab: the first *flair* shown
- on the Vote to Close dialog: the first *close option*
- on tag stats pages: both *answerer* and *asker* columns are misaligned *(credit to Sanoj in comments)*
- on Answer Edit page: question title link and question preview box *(see self-referential example)*

[alt text http://imagebin.ca/img/NlqutfB.png](http://imagebin.ca/img/NlqutfB.png)

---

[alt text http://imagebin.ca/img/c1aeP1Lz.png](http://imagebin.ca/img/c1aeP1Lz.png)

---

[alt text http://imagebin.ca/img/byCoCUI.png](http://imagebin.ca/img/byCoCUI.png)